# How do I use JavaScript loop and save result in local storage on AMP PAGES

Tags: javascript, wordpress, amp-html

```
   var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i].href.substr(links[i].href.length - 4) == '.pdf') {
        linksa1 = links[i].href;
        var linksa=linksa1;
        var linksb =linksa.substring(0, linksa.lastIndexOf('/'));
        var links2 =linksb.replace('/download/', '/embed/');
        break;
    }
        else if (links[i].href.substr(links[i].href.length - 7) == 'sharing') {
        links2 = links[i].href;
        links2 = links2.split('/').slice(0,-1).join('/')+'/preview';
        //document.write(links2);
        break;
    }
}

if( typeof links2 == 'undefined' ) {
    document.getElementById("myh1").innerHTML = "عذرًا ، لم نتمكن من إعداد كتابك للقراءة - يمكنك بدلاً من ذلك الرجوع وتنزيله";
};
localStorage.setItem('links5',links2);
```

The above looks for hyperlinks that ends with .pdf on any post i make, it makes some modificaton to the result and save it in localstorage.

The code works fine with normal posts but i have not been able to make it work on AMP pages.
I have tried wrapping the code in `<script id="myscript" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">`
but still no positive results yet. Can someone help and give a clue on what i should do. I am using wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Have you added amp-script tag in HTML?

```
<amp-script layout="container" script="myscript" class="amp-my-custom-script">
  
  <!-- your html goes here  -->

</amp-script>
```

This should work with script tag that you have already mentioned:

```
<script id="myscript" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
```

Also you probably need to put this in `<head>`:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js"></script>
```

Find more in [AMP DOCS](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/) about amp-script component